# Blocked Loading HTTP Mixed Content on Heroku

Tags: javascript, ajax, heroku

I am creating a web app with Node.js and Express. When I try to upload my project to Heroku, all of my content loads successfully on the page, but I get an error when I try to perform any action that requires an AJAX call to the API I'm working with:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://farmers-market-finder.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS,
>   but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   http://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/v1/data.svc/zipSearch?zip=94118.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I'm working with an API of farmer's market data, made by the USDA, and have followed their suggested format for RESTful AJAX requests:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/v1/data.svc/mktDetail?id=' + id, 
    async: false,
    success: function (data) { ... }
    })
```

I have done a lot of research on Stack Overflow and other sites about this Mixed Content error. Most answers suggest that the 'GET' request route needs to be changed to "https://..." in order to work on Heroku's https server. I tried switching this, but the route to the API no longer works; I get a 404 Not Found error. I also tried switching my route to a relative link (just writing url: '//search.ams...') but that got the same 404 error. Seems like I really do need an http:// link to reach the API I'm trying to access.

Does anyone know of a way to get Heroku to allow me to use an "http" link, instead of https, or some other way to successfully make the request?

Answer (score 2):

In your server.js file, add this code above your other app.use statements. (App = expr

```
app.use(function (req, res, next){
  if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https') {
    res.redirect('http://' + req.hostname + req.url);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```